# Why is `$scope.apply` needed here?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wonijucigu/1/edit?html,js,output)

I don't quite understand this directive definition:

```
.directive('ngFocus', [function() {
  var FOCUS_CLASS = "ng-focused";
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$focused = false;
      element.bind('focus', function(evt) {
        element.addClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
        scope.$apply(function() {ctrl.$focused = true;});
      }).bind('blur', function(evt) {
        element.removeClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
        scope.$apply(function() {ctrl.$focused = false;});
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

The `scope.$apply(function() {ctrl.$focused = true；});` looks a bit weird. Shouldn't `ctrl` be the same as `scope.signupform.name`? And in the HTML tag `<div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.name.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid && !signup_form.name.$focused">`, the `signup_form.name.$focused` is already being watched. Why couldn't I just use `ctrl.$focused=true` without being wrapped with `scope.$apply`..

Moreover, I found this DEMO doesn't work well. The error message is expected to hide until the field loses focus.. However, in the picture below, the error message is displayed while the field still keeps focused..

[image: screencast]

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: This is just a quirk of 1.2.0-rc.2 version of Angular. Change the version to a higher version and `scope.$apply` will not be required